# ReactVR how properly set pointer (raycaster)

Tags: javascript, virtual-reality, react-360

I used code (installing it wasn't working for me) from [simple-raycaster](https://github.com/mathdroid/simple-raycaster) to display pointer on my VR screen, it works but with some problem - 'behind' me there is square space where this pointer disappears and didn't work. Any idea how can I fix that?

Comment: Can you share your code? It's hard to know what's going on without knowing what you are doing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into an issue similar to what you describe.  I had several Text elements placed at various locations.  I had each wrapped in a VrButton with a onEnter and onExit calling functions to set timeouts gaze select an item.  I was seeing the raycaster disappear in a section of space directly behind me.  I eventually figured out that if I remove the VrButton wrapper and placed the onEnter and onExit directly on the Text element it solved the problem.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe it doesn't exactly solve the problem but at least now I know what causes that ;)